# What additional condition is necessary so that $f$ perserves the topology?

Tags: general-topology

If $f$ is continuous and surjective and is a mapping $f: X \to Y$ with topological spaces $X,Y$ (different topologies). Will it carry the topologies? For example, if $X$ is compact and connected, will $f(X)$ carry the property and its subspaces $U_i \subset X$? Is injectivity required?

Comment: Compactness and connectedness will be preserved, but in general this won't carry all the things. For instance, you can find open sets that are not going to open sets. (In case this is what you were asking)

Comment: Hang on, if $O \subset X$ is closed (hence compact in $X$), then $f(O)$ is compact (and hence closed). Why would it not carry? You just said they will be preserved

Comment: Here you are assuming $X$ is compact, right? Why is $f(O)$ closed?

Comment: @Shoutre, yes I am assuming $X$ is compact. Compact sets are closed no?

Comment: I believe you are confused because you are assuming the fact only valid for Hausdorff spaces that compact subsets are closed. If then $Y$ is Hausdorff, you are correct and the mapping $f$ will be a closed map (sends closed sets to closed sets) and hence, if $f$ is also injective, it is a homeomorphism ($X$ and $Y$ have identical topological structures)

Comment: So what is wrong with my original reasoning?

Comment: @Shoutre, but homemorphisms preserves everything right?

Comment: Yes, but a continuous and surjective mapping $f\colon X\to Y$ is not necessarily a homeomorphism. If you add the conditions: $Y$ is Hausdorff and $f$ is injective, then it becomes a homeomorphism.

Comment: @Shoutre, so you are saying homemoprhisms isn't not enough, it is dependant on what type of topological spaces the homeomorphism is?

Comment: A homeomorphism is a bijective continuous function with a continuous inverse function. Homeomorphisms preserve topological structures between topological spaces: everything. In the above comment, I gave some sufficient conditions under which a continuous surjective $f\colon X\to Y$ is actually a homeomorphism.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'carry the topologies'? Do you mean that it is an open map (image of open sets are open)? Or a homeomorphism (continuous with continuous inverse; invertibility implies bijection)?

Comment: @Shoutre, but you just said the map $f$ would need require injectivity to be a homemorphism, by definition. The fact that $Y$ should also be Hausdroff seems to be more

Comment: @JustinBenfield the topological features and properties.

Comment: @jacobsmith: Do you mean topological *invariants*? Those are properties determined by the topology of the space in question, hence two spaces, *that are homeomorphic*, have the same invariants. The reverse is not always true, and depends on what topological invariants you are considering.

Comment: Asking $f$ injective and $Y$ Hausdorff is a sufficient condition, not necessary for $f$ to be a homeomorphism. It should help to read again the definitions again and to make some examples of continuous functions.

Comment: @Shoutre https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism only says bijective continuous map.

Comment: @jacobsmith: Actually, it says: "a homeomorphism or topological isomorphism or bi continuous function is a continuous function between topological spaces that has a continuous inverse function."

Comment: @Shoutre: It’s not true that compact sets are closed **only** if the space is Hausdorff. Spaces in which compact sets are closed are called $KC$-spaces. Of course all Hausdorff spaces are $KC$-spaces, but the converse is false: the [Alexandrov extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension) of $\Bbb Q$ is a well-known example of a non-Hausdorff $KC$-space.

Comment: I intended to say that Hausdorff is a sufficient condition to guarantee that compact subsets are closed, but in putting emphasis on this fact I accidentaly said "only if". You are right.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate why $f:X\rightarrow Y$ surjective and continuous is not enough to ensure homeomorphism (preservation of *all* topological properties), consider the $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$ (or a closed interval $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$, if you want compact and connected $X$).

Let $X$ be endowed with the standard topology, and $Y$ the indiscrete topology. Then this map is continuous: inverse image of the open sets, $\emptyset$ and $Y=\mathbb{R}$ or $Y=[a,b]$ are open in the relevant topologies.

(Note: In the case of $[a,b]$ is it open in the subspace topology it inherits from $\mathbb{R}$, which would be the standard topology of $X$ for the case of $X=[a,b]$.)

Yet the two spaces are not at all homeomorphic. For example, $X$ is Hausdorff but $Y$ is not.